# How to write if condtional statement in jasmine javascript?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a if  block condition. I need to write test case for that if condition in jasmine javascript.While referring this website

https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_matcher.html

**This is my code in if block:-**

```
if(!isNullorUndefined(amp))
var a=amp;
```

**Expectation:-**

1.If the **amp** value is undefined,the condition is to be false.

2.If the **amp**  had value,the second statement gonna to be executed.

for second line,i can able to write jasmine code

```
expect(a).tobe(amp)
```

I am little confused,how to implement the jasmine js for if blocks.Could you anyone provide me an simple example for if condition block in jasmine js.

A simple example is might be helpful?

Could anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: just create two different tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For testing Not null or Undefined , you can write like this.

```
describe("Your Test Controller",() => {
    it("check for not null or undefined", function (){
        expect(Function(params)).not.toBeNull();
        expect(Function(params)).not.toBeUndefined();
    });
   }
```

and if you want to test for being null and undefined

```
describe("Your Test Controller",() => {
        it("check for null or undefined", function (){
            expect(Function(params)).toBeNull();
            expect(Function(params)).toBeUndefined();
        });
       }
```

Answer (score 4):

not sure if I understood correct.

you could write a cutsom matcher as described there

or you would do two tests as in

```
describe("Test amp", function() {
    it("cechk amp to be undef", function (){
        expect(yourFunction('test')).toBe(undef);
    });
    it("gives true if number", function (){
        expect(yourFunction('test2')).toBe('your Testresult');
    });
});
```

hope it helps